# filter based on first two letters of a column

Tags: awk, comparison, filtering

I have a file that looks like this:

```
345-103832 OI.S.15.0FKOGO   
345-103832 OX.S.5.0FKOGO   
345-103832 QX.S.3.0FKOGO  
345-103832 Qa.S.21.0FKOGO  
345-114643 IX.S.13.0FKOGY
```

I need to print all lines that column 2 does not start with "O", with "I" or have an "O or "I" as part of the first two letters.

So, I would like something like:

```sh
awk '{ if( $2 != * O. || $2 != O *. || $2 != * I. || $2 != I *.) print $0}' ...
```

In such a way that the result should be:

```
345-103832 QX.S.3.0FKOGO  
345-103832 Qa.S.21.0FKOGO
```

Can you help me on that?

Comment: Dear Eugenia, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is an excellent well-written question! We don't often see new users adding all the needed information on the first try. Nonetheless, don't be afraid to take the [tour]. Looking forward to seeing more of your questions and answers in this forum.

Comment: What @kvantour except I don't see how the title matches the question? Oh, it's a capital i, not a pipe. Well, still...

Comment: @JamesBrown mismatching capital `I` with a `|` or `O` with a zero `0` is the fault of fontsettings and not the OP ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
awk '$2 !~ /^.?[OI]/' file
```

See the [`awk` online demo](https://ideone.com/XSW3j6).

The `'$2 !~ /^.?[OI]/'` means: print all lines where Field 2 does not match:

- `^` - start of line
- `.?` - any 1 optional char
- `[OI]` - either `O` or `I`.

The first two letters must be letters, replace `.` with `[[:alpha:]]` or `[A-Z]`, just choose what is best as per your requirements.